# Hypothesis test for classification model

Tags: classification, anova, t-test, post-hoc, ab-test

I have a model that outputs 0 or 1 for interest/not-interest in a job. I'm doing an A/B/C test comparing two models (treatment groups) and none (control group).

ANOVA for hypothesis testing and t-test with Bonferroni correction for posthoc testing is my plan. But both tests assume normality.

Can we have normality for 0 and 1? If so, how? If not, what's the best test (including posthoc)?

Comment: Are you using models like logistic regressions, neural networks, or random forests that return probability-like values that you round to 0/1, or do your models literally return the hard categories?

Comment: In the experiment, the user will either click/not-click a particular job post, so it should be 0 and 1. Though in the model it returns probability. @Dave